# How can i pass additional values to winston logger

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I am using winston to handle my logging for my nodejs backend. in my case i created some custom levels to have logs written to a more specific category like security , db etc. All works fine, except that I would like to specify a extra label when i write to file like severity.
So in my case I use the label like security to write all security related messages to the file.
Both of the below calls do the same in my case

```
 logger.security( 'We have the latest db vesion ' + Date())
 logger.log('security','We have the latest db vesion ' + Date());
```

And produce an output in log file like this

```
2021-01-28 15:05:29.869 [undefined] security: We have the latest db vesion Thu Jan 28 2021 15:05:29 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

myFormat looks like this

```
const myFormat = printf(({ level, message, label, timestamp }) => {
    return `${timestamp} [${label}] ${level}: ${message}`;
})
```

So my question is how can I pass the label to the log when i call the log function ? Also is there a way to apply a color to my label ? I am planning to use the label to specify the severity of the log entry like info or error in my security log.